# How to assign a reference to a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am working with a complex dictionary and want to make it easy to work just assigning a variable to it.

```
myDictionay["with"]["complex"]["sub"]["dictionary"] = "NewValue"
```

I just want this:

```
let smaller = myDictionay["with"]["complex"]["sub"]
smaller["dictionary"] = "NewValue"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: @PetahChristian Those are not duplicate. He asks how to define a pointer to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

The Swift `Dictionary` (and `Array` / `Set`) follows pass by reference semantics, rather than pass by value semantics (if you look in the headers you'll see it is a `struct`, not a `class`).  This means that when you assign a `Dictionary` instance from one variable to another variable, and change the value associated with the new variable, it **does not** in fact change the value associated with the original value.  As such, the syntax you are looking for is not possible with a Swift `Dictionary`.  Having said that, you can always use an `NSMutableDictionary` instead, and then the syntax you are hoping for will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure to perform the inner access for you:

```
let smaller : (inout _: [String : [String : [String :[String : String]]]], key: String, val: String) -> () = { dict, key, val in
    dict["with"]?["complex"]?["sub"]?[key] = val
    return ()
}

/* setup example */
var a = [String : String]()
var b = [String :[String : String]]()
var c = [String : [String : [String : String]]]()
var myDictionary = [String : [String : [String :[String : String]]]]()

a["dictionary"] = "OldValue"
b["sub"] = a
b["anothersub"] = a
c["complex"] = b
myDictionary["with"] = c

/* example */
print(myDictionary)
/* ["with": ["complex": ["anothersub": ["dictionary": "OldValue"],
    "sub": ["dictionary": "OldValue"]]]] */

smaller(&myDictionary, key: "dictionary", val: "NewValue")
print(myDictionary)
/* ["with": ["complex": ["anothersub": ["dictionary": "OldValue"],
    "sub": ["dictionary": "NewValue"]]]] */
```

Or, more condensed: you can use a closure specifically with a dictionary name accessible in the scope where closure is used (i.e., no need to send a reference to the dictionary as an argument to the closure).

```
let smaller2 : (String, String) -> () = { myDictionary["with"]?["complex"]?["sub"]?[$0] = $1 }
smaller2("dictionary", "NewerValue")
print(myDictionary)
/* ["with": ["complex": ["anothersub": ["dictionary": "OldValue"],
    "sub": ["dictionary": "NewerValue"]]]] */
```

---

If you're handling your dictionary `myDictionary` as some class property, you could, as an alternative to the above, define a class method that returns closures as the ones above, given a "dictionary key path", e.g. `"with.complex.sub"`, as argument:

```
/* say 'myDictionary' is some class property (initialized as in example above)
   In same class, introduce the following method */
func dictClosure(dictKeyPath: String) -> ((String, String) -> ()) {
    let arr = dictKeyPath.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    if arr.count == 3 {
        return {
            myDictionary[arr[0]]?[arr[1]]?[arr[2]]?[$0] = $1 }
    }
    else {
        return {
            _, _ in
            print("This closure is invalid")
        }
    }
}

/* example usage */
var smaller3 = dictClosure("with.complex.sub")
smaller3("dictionary", "NewestValue")
smaller3 = dictClosure("with.complex.anothersub")
smaller3("dictionary", "AlsoNewValue")
print(myDictionary)
/* ["with": ["complex": ["anothersub": ["dictionary": "AlsoNewValue"], 
    "sub": ["dictionary": "NewestValue"]]]] */
```

The above assumes dictionary key paths of three levels (`"one.two.three"`), and yields a closure for accessing the dictionary on the fourth level.

---

Finally note that for all solutions above, calling the `smaller` closures will allow for *adding* new key-value pairs into the fourth level of the dictionary, not only mutating the value of existing pairs. E.g. the key typo `smaller3("dcitionary", "NewValue")` will add a key-value pair `"dcitionary": "NewValue"` into the fourth level dictionary. If you only want to allow mutating values for existing key, simply add `?` after the inner-most key access in the `smaller` closures above:

```
/* smaller ... */
dict["with"]?["complex"]?["sub"]?[key]? = val

/* smaller2 ... */
myDictionary["with"]?["complex"]?["sub"]?[$0]? = $1

/* smaller3 ... */
myDictionary[arr[0]]?[arr[1]]?[arr[2]]?[$0]? = $1
```